# templates won't work after adding migrations

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-migrations

I added the data via migration and now after running `migrate` and `makemigrations`
i tried to `runserver` and there are NoReverseMatch Errors everywhere.

Take a look at this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /blog/

Reverse for 'blog_post_detail' with keyword
arguments '{'year': 2008, 'month': 9, 'slug': 'django-10-released'}'
not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
['(?P<year>\\d{4}/)^(?P<month>\\d{1,2}/)^(?P<slug>\\w+)/$']
```

In Migration it looks like this :

```
POSTS = [
    {
        "title": "Django 1.0 Release",
        "slug": "django-10-released",
        "pub_date": date(2008, 9, 3),
        "startups": [],
        "tags": ["django", "python", "web"],
        "text": "THE Web Framework.",
    },]
```

This is the actual urlpattern:

```
    re_path (r'^(?P<year>\d{4}/)'
        r'^(?P<month>\d{1,2}/)'
        r'^(?P<slug>\w+)/$',post_detail,name='blog_post_detail'),
```

Similarly every template has the same problem....

[image: https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/402509285443188651/]

Comment: Please don't use `>` to indent code or error messages. It hides angled brackets, so it shows `['(?P\d{4}/)^(?P\d{1,2}/)^(?P\w+)/$']` instead of `['(?P<year>\\d{4}/)^(?P<month>\\d{1,2}/)^(?P<slug>\\w+)/$']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` matches the start of the string, so you shouldn't never include it in the middle of a regex. Remove it from the `month` and `slug` strings. You should also move the forward slashes outside of the named groups. If your slugs contain hyphens, then you need to use `[\w-]+` instead of `\w+`.

```
re_path (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/'
    r'(?P<month>\d{1,2})/'
    r'(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',post_detail,name='blog_post_detail'),
```

Personally, I find this regex harder when it's split over multiple lines. I would prefer:

```
re_path (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
         post_detail,name='blog_post_detail'),
```

Comment: but the problem is with every template..and their regex is very simle

Comment: I don’t understand your comment. My answer might not solve your problem, but it will at least give you a different error message. Unless I know the code you are running and the error message you get, I can’t help.

Comment: with your regex the error is still the same ...its not a different error..and the error as i mentioned is NoReverseMatch

Comment: and before i added the migrations everything worked just fine..There was no NoReversematch error ..I added the data in migrations via list and dict ...Hope that gives u some insight

Comment: i used the `flush` command and templates are now working but the objects that i created in migrations are not being displayed in templates..

Comment: The code in your question still has `^`s and `/`s in the wrong places. If you use my answer, then you might still get `NoReversematch`, but the exact error messgae text will be different. I can't help because I don't know the exact code and error message.

Comment: [`flush`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#flush) removes all data from the datababase. If there aren't any items in your database, then the code to reverse the URL doesn't run, so you don't get the error. As the docs suggest, you might want to drop the database and run `migrate`, which will re-run all the migrations.

Comment: There isn’t a Django command to drop the database. If you are using `SQLite` you can delete the `db.sqlite3` file.

Comment: You are Right ...the error is back and i have fixed the regex and used the regex u provided..Can u point me in the right direction ,i mean what should i do? I added the screenshot above

Comment: I noticed another problem in the regex - it doesn’t handle hyphens in the slug. See the updated answer above.